# Tagging using Azure Policy and Terraform templates ignoring tags

Tags: azure, terraform

I am trying to achieve the following:

- Using the lifecycle command to ignore tags being applied to resources by Azure Policy.

**Background**
I have a terraform template that applies tags to the resource group but the resources in the same template do not have tags applied. Instead, I have an Azure Policy that enforced inheritance of tags from the resource groups.

When I make any changes to the template and run **terraform plan** I get a load of changes occur which state they will change the tags from values to null. This isn't causing any issue as such; it just bloats my terraform plan with unnecessary changes.

**Issue**
I have tried using the **lifecycle** command to says ignore changes and set the value to tags, however it doesn't seem to work, and the plan still shows the tags are going to be removed.

Below is an example of a resource that says the tags will be removed if a change occurs.

**Example Code**

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "ext_ade" {
   depends_on = [azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.ext_domain_join, azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.ext_dsc]
   count = var.session_hosts.quantity
    name = var.ext_ade.name  
    virtual_machine_id = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.vm.*.id[count.index]
    publisher = "Microsoft.Azure.Security"
    type = "AzureDiskEncryption"
    type_handler_version = "2.2"
    auto_upgrade_minor_version = true

    settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "EncryptionOperation": "EnableEncryption",
        "KeyVaultURL": "${data.azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.vault_uri}",
        "KeyVaultResourceId": "${data.azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.id}",
        "KeyEncryptionKeyURL": "${azurerm_key_vault_key.ade_key.*.id[count.index]}",
        "KekVaultResourceId": "${data.azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.id}",
        "KeyEncryptionAlgorithm": "RSA-OAEP",
        "VolumeType": "All"
    }
    SETTINGS

    lifecycle {
      ignore_changes = [settings,tags]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Tagging using Azure Policy and Terraform templates ignoring tags

I've tried in my environment and was able to deploy it successfully using ***lifecycle*** command.

Taken a snippet of `Terraform` from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64141883/azure-disk-encryption-via-terraform-with-key-vault-vmextensionprovisioninger) solution given by @Jim Xu and modified it to meet your requirements as shown below:

***main.tf***

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=2.99.0"
    }
  }
}
provider "azurerm" {
        features {}

}
resource "random_string" "password" {
  length  = 16
  special = false
}
data "azurerm_resource_group" "newtest" {
  name = var.resource_group_name
}
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "keyvault" {
  name                = var.key_vault_name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
   enabled_for_disk_encryption = true
   enabled_for_deployment=true
   enabled_for_template_deployment =true
   location=data.azurerm_resource_group.newtest.location
   tenant_id = "<tenant-id>"
   sku_name = "standard"
   soft_delete_retention_days=90
   
}
resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "myPolicy" {
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.keyvault.id
  tenant_id = "<tenant-id>"
  object_id = "<object-id>"
  key_permissions = [
    "Create",
    "Delete",
    "Get",
    "Purge",
    "Recover",
    "Update",
    "List",
    "Decrypt",
    "Sign"
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_key" "testKEK" {
  name         = "testKEK"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.keyvault.id
  key_type     = "RSA"
  key_size     = 2048
   depends_on = [
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.myPolicy
  ]
  key_opts = [
    "decrypt",
    "encrypt",
    "sign",
    "unwrapKey",
    "verify",
    "wrapKey",
  ]
}
 
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "vmextension" {
  name                       = random_string.password.result
  virtual_machine_id         = "/subscriptions/<subscription_ID>/resourceGroups/<resourceGroup>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/<VMName>"
  publisher                  = "Microsoft.Azure.Security"
  type                       = "AzureDiskEncryption"
  type_handler_version       = var.type_handler_version
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = true

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "EncryptionOperation": "${var.encrypt_operation}",
        "KeyVaultURL": "${azurerm_key_vault.keyvault.vault_uri}",
        "KeyVaultResourceId": "${azurerm_key_vault.keyvault.id}",                   
        "KeyEncryptionKeyURL": "${azurerm_key_vault_key.testKEK.id}",
        "KekVaultResourceId": "${azurerm_key_vault.keyvault.id}",                   
        "KeyEncryptionAlgorithm": "${var.encryption_algorithm}",
        "VolumeType": "${var.volume_type}"
    }
SETTINGS

 lifecycle {
      ignore_changes = [settings,tags]
    } 
}
```

***variable.tf:***

```
variable "resource_group_name" {
  default     = "newtest"
}
variable "location" {
  default     = "EastUS"
}
variable key_vault_name {
  default     = ""
}
variable virtual_machine_id {
    default     = ""
}
variable "volume_type" {
  default = "All"
}
variable "encrypt_operation" {
  default = "EnableEncryption"
}
variable "type_handler_version" {
  description = "Defaults to 2.2 on Windows"
  default     = "2.2"
}
```

***Note***: you can modify the `tfvars` file to suit your needs.

***Executed*** `terraform init` or `terraform init -upgrade`:

[image]

***Executed*** `terraform plan`:

[image]

[image]

***Give*** `terraform apply` ***after running the above commands successfully***:

[image]

***Created and observed no changes in keyvault from Portal***:

[image]

***ResourceGroup(newtest) deployed in Portal:***

[image]